# Data Set for Predictive Modelling

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

Can anyone direct me to a good source?

I am after a data set with:
1) A numeric or Binary DV
2) At least 6 possible predictor variables
3) At least one categorical predictor variable
4) At least 100 cases

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Predictive modeling of what?  (I have no idea what 'DV' means in this context ... I assume it's *not* Digital Video)

Comment: I guess DV stands for _dependent variable_. R package _AER_ has plenty of datasets available that satisfy some or all the conditions.

Comment: It would be helpful to understand what you want this to be predictive of (climate modeling, population models, biological sampling, ...) and some more details so the community can help you find what you need.

Answer (score 4):

Kaggle hosts [predictive modeling competitions](http://www.kaggle.com/competitions) where you might find the data set you are looking for to test your model.

Answer (score 4):

If you're already using a Python toolchain, then the easiest option is probably [skdata](http://jaberg.github.io/skdata/). See the [data sets it provides](https://github.com/jaberg/skdata/wiki/Data-Set-Modules).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the homepages of machine learning toolkits like [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/). It has a subpage [Datasets](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/datasets.html) containing several collections of datasets. I went for the first one, [datasets-UCI.jar](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/weka/datasets-UCI.jar), renamed to .zip to extract the individual datasets and opened the first one, `anneal.arff`, in a text editor:

1. Nominal or numeric class (not sure from description)
2. 38 possible predictor variables: 3 integer, 29 nominal, 6 continuous
3. Check.
4. 798 instances.

Answer (score 2):

[UCI](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/) hosts a Machine Learning Repository with many datasets that are labeled by about method, type, etc.

[**LINK**](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html)

In R there is a package 'readMLData' to read these datasets directly ([PDF details](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readMLData/readMLData.pdf)).

With Python you can use the sklearn package to load many of the datasets ([link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/)).